# Assign value inside CASE statement TSQL gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to TSQL and trying to migrate MySQL to TSQL which gives an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

SQL Query With Binding parameters:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
         content.content_id       AS content_id ,
         content.content_type     AS content_type ,
         content.content_name     AS content_name ,
         content.content_version  AS content_version ,
         content.effective_date   AS effective_date      
FROM     test_content content
WHERE    content.vendor_id = :vendor_id
AND      content.content_type = :content_type
AND
   CASE
       WHEN :content_type2 <> 'T' 
       THEN content.content_name = :content_name
       ELSE 1=1
   END
ORDER BY content_version DESC
```

SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
         content.content_id       AS content_id ,
         content.content_type     AS content_type ,
         content.content_name     AS content_name ,
         content.content_version  AS content_version ,
         content.effective_date   AS effective_date      
FROM     test_content content
WHERE    content.vendor_id = 127
AND      content.content_type = 'E'
AND
   CASE
       WHEN 'E' <> 'T' 
       THEN content.content_name = 'ABC'
       ELSE 1=1
   END
ORDER BY content_version DESC
```

It seems an issue with `THEN` content.content_name = 'ABC'.
Is there any way to assign dynamic data inside the CASE expression?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: `CASE`, in T-SQL, is an **expression** not a statement. It returns a scalar value, not a boolean result. Although your `CASE` expression doesn't make any sense, you could just replace it with `content.content_name = 'ABC'` and get the result you want. There is never an instance when the character `'E'` is equal to the character `'T'`.

Comment: Also, you have an additional trailing comma after `AS effective_date ,` which'll cause an error.

Comment: You wrote `CASE` that will always return `content.content_name = 'ABC'`, because `E` is always different then `T`. So you don't need `CASE` here, just put `content.content_name = 'ABC'`

Comment: `WHERE ... AND (:content_type2 = 'T' OR content.content_name = 'ABC')`.

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic These are dynamic binding parameters where the value will be dynamic. I have updated the question.

Comment: `:vendor_id` isn't valid T-SQL, @HemantKumar ; are you *sure* you're using SQL Sevrer?

Comment: Yup this is SQL query executed with PHP PDO and :vendor_id is dynamic binding parameters with the query in php.

Comment: A [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression cannot return a [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?#boolean-data-type) data type. This is "documented" by virtue of [Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?#return-types) referencing [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) which does not list `boolean` as a data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this what you expect?

```
    SELECT TOP(1)
     content.content_id       AS content_id ,
     content.content_type     AS content_type ,
     content.content_name     AS content_name ,
     content.content_version  AS content_version ,
     content.effective_date   AS effective_date      
   FROM     test_content content
   WHERE    content.vendor_id = :vendor_id
   AND      content.content_type = :content_type
   AND      content.content_name = 
               CASE
                WHEN :content_type2 <> 'T' 
                THEN :content_name
                ELSE content.content_name
               END
   ORDER BY content_version DESC
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the original query if `content.content_name` is `NULL`. This can be "fixed" by throwing in an `ISNULL`, but that has performance implications. There is no good case for `CASE` here (pardon the pun).

Comment: Thanks, @prem it worked. It would be great if you explain this solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly guessing here, but what I think you need is something like this:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
         content_id,
         content_type,
         CASE WHEN @content_type2 = 'T' 
         THEN content_name 
         ELSE @content_name 
         END AS content_name,
         content_version ,
         effective_date      
FROM     test_content
WHERE    vendor_id = @vendor_id
AND      content_type = @content_type
ORDER BY content_version DESC
```

Note that in SQL Server parameters (and variables) are prefixed with @.  I have also got rid of all the superfluous aliasing.  Finally it is easier to read if the case statement is put the other way round, i.e. what happens when @content_type2 = 'T' followed by else.  What is important here, is that the case is part of the SELECT not the WHERE.

Of course I may have misunderstood totally!

EDIT  Reading again perhaps what you were after is:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
         content_id,
         content_type,
         content_name,
         content_version ,
         effective_date      
FROM     test_content
WHERE    vendor_id = @vendor_id
AND      content_type = @content_type
AND      (@content_type2 = 'T' OR content_name = @content_name)
ORDER BY content_version DESC
```